# ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 3 syntax errors that in parts are ignored why?

Tags: vhdl

I need to write this state machine to control a fifo datapath, yet syntax errors that seem to be ignored in other parts don't let me complete the state machine properly.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity FIFO_FSM is
    Port ( CMD_WR_H : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CMD_RD_H : in  STD_LOGIC;
           SYS_CLK_H : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST_H : in  STD_LOGIC;
           EMPTY_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           FULL_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LD_EN_0_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LD_EN_1_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LD_EN_2_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LD_EN_3_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           RD_EN_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           WR_EN_H : out  STD_LOGIC;
           LD_RVR_H : out  STD_LOGIC);
end FIFO_FSM;

architecture Behavioral of FIFO_FSM is
signal PresentState,Nextstate: integer := 0;
begin

process(PresentState,CMD_WR_H,CMD_RD_H,RST_H)
begin

case PresentState is

when 0 => -- empty state
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='1';FULL_H<='0';
if(RST_H ='1') then Nextstate<=0;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H ='1' and  CMD_RD_H='1') and ( RST_H='0'))) then Nextstate<=0;
elsif((((CMD_WR_H='0') and (CMD_RD_H='0' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=0;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H='0' and (CMD_RD_H='1' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=0; 
elsif(((( CMD_WR_H='1') and  CMD_RD_H='0') and ( RST_H='0')) )then Nextstate<=1;
end if;

when 1 => --loading Reg 0 transition state
LD_EN_0_H <='1';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='1';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=2;


when 20=> -- unloading R0
LD_EN_0_H <='1';LD_EN_1_H <='1';LD_EN_2_H <='1';LD_EN_3_H <='1';
RD_EN_H<='1';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='1';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=0;

when 2=>  -- Reg 0 stored
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
if(RST_H ='1') then Nextstate<=0;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H ='1' and  CMD_RD_H='1') and ( RST_H='0'))) then Nextstate<=2;
elsif((((CMD_WR_H='0') and (CMD_RD_H='0' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=2;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H='0' and (CMD_RD_H='1' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=20; 
elsif(((( CMD_WR_H='1') and  CMD_RD_H='0') and ( RST_H='0')) )then Nextstate<=3;
end if;

when 3=> --Load Reg 1 transition state
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='1';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='1';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=4;

when 42 => --unloading R1
LD_EN_0_H <='1';LD_EN_1_H <='1';LD_EN_2_H <='1';LD_EN_3_H <='1';
RD_EN_H<='1';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='1';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=2;


when 4=> --Reg 1 Stored
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
if(RST_H ='1') then Nextstate<=0;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H ='1' and  CMD_RD_H='1') and ( RST_H='0'))) then Nextstate<=4;
elsif((((CMD_WR_H='0') and (CMD_RD_H='0' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=4;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H='0' and (CMD_RD_H='1' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=42; 
elsif(((( CMD_WR_H='1') and  CMD_RD_H='0') and ( RST_H='0')) )then Nextstate<=5;
end if;

when 5=> --Load Reg 2 transition state
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='1';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='1';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=6;

when 64 -- unloading R2
LD_EN_0_H <='1';LD_EN_1_H <='1';LD_EN_2_H <='1';LD_EN_3_H <='1';
RD_EN_H<='1';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='1';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=4;

when 6=> -- Reg 2 Stored
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
if(RST_H ='1') then Nextstate<=0;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H ='1' and  CMD_RD_H='1') and ( RST_H='0'))) then Nextstate<=6;
elsif((((CMD_WR_H='0') and (CMD_RD_H='0' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=6;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H='0' and (CMD_RD_H='1' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=64; 
elsif(((( CMD_WR_H='1') and  CMD_RD_H='0') and ( RST_H='0')) )then Nextstate<=7;
end if;

when 7=> -- Load Reg 3 transition state
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='1';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='1';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=8;

when 86 -- unloading R3
LD_EN_0_H <='1';LD_EN_1_H <='1';LD_EN_2_H <='1';LD_EN_3_H <='1';
RD_EN_H<='1';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='1';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='0';
Nextstate<=6;

when 8=> -- Reg 3 Stored
LD_EN_0_H <='0';LD_EN_1_H <='0';LD_EN_2_H <='0';LD_EN_3_H <='0';
RD_EN_H<='0';WR_EN_H<='0';LD_RVR_H<='0';
EMPTY_H<='0';FULL_H<='1';
if(RST_H ='1') then Nextstate<=0;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H ='1' and  CMD_RD_H='1') and ( RST_H='0'))) then Nextstate<=8;
elsif((((CMD_WR_H='0') and (CMD_RD_H='0' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=8;
elsif(((CMD_WR_H='0' and (CMD_RD_H='1' )) and ( RST_H='0')))then Nextstate<=86; 
elsif(((( CMD_WR_H='1') and  CMD_RD_H='0') and ( RST_H='0')) )then Nextstate<=8;
end if;

end process;

process(CLK)                          -- State Register
   begin
      if CLK='1' and CLK'EVENT then      -- rising edge of clock
         PresentState <= Nextstate;
     end if;
   end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I get  these errors:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/willow/workspaceVHDL/FSM/FIFO_FSM.vhd" Line 96: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/willow/workspaceVHDL/FSM/FIFO_FSM.vhd" Line 119: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/willow/workspaceVHDL/FSM/FIFO_FSM.vhd" Line 135: Syntax error near "process".
```

What I'm trying to ask is what is the error and how to fix it, because is saying like I can't use `<=` to assign a value to my inputs and outputs but only in certain lines and not in others where it let's it be. The other error I get is near the end process line just before the process with sensitivity to the clock.

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: sorry is my first question here, what I'm trying to ask is what is the error and how to fix it, because is saying like I can't use <=  to assign a value to my inputs and outputs but only in certain lines and not in others where it let's it be, also the other error I get is near the end process line just before the process with sensitivity to the clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should really format your code to make it readable:

- Indent your code to match the logical hierarchy
- Avoid multiple assignments on the same line
- Use spaces between operators

Your code may make sense to you now, but when you come back to this code in a few months, or if somebody else has to work with it, the benefit of well formatted code will quickly become apparent.

Your first and second errors are because you have e.g. `when 64`, forgetting the `=>`. It should say e.g. `when 64 =>`.

The third error is because you have a `case` statement, without a matching `end case`. Your statement should look something like this:

```
case PresentState is
  when 0 =>
    -- do something
  when 1 =>
    -- do something else
end case;
```

The final line here is what you are missing.

Having resolved the case statement problems, the next issue is that your code uses `CLK`, which is not an input to your entity.

The next problem is that your case statement doesn't cover all the possible cases. You can resolve this either by adding a final `when others =>` case at the end of the case statement or by using an enumerated type for the case statement. The enumerated type would be my choice, to preserve readability:

```
type STATE_MACHINE_type is (IDLE, LOAD_DATA, RESET);
signal PresentState : STATE_MACHINE_type := IDLE;
```

...

```
case PresentState is
  when IDLE =>
    Nextstate <= LOAD_DATA;
  when LOAD_DATA =>
    Nextstate <= RESET;
  when RESET =>
    Nextstate <= IDLE;
end case;
```

If you decide to use the `when others =>` approach, but have no code to put in this case, you can make this explicit using `NULL`:

```
case PresentState is
  when 0 =>
    -- do something
  when others =>
    NULL;
end case;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'm currently taking a class but mostly we have had to learn the language on our own hence my errors because I really haven't found a good source to get to know the language like there are many for programming languages.

Comment: Nobody starts off an expert! With the changes I suggest, your code does at least compile, so I think this answers your question.

Comment: thanks a lot scary_jeff , I got the code fixed, may I ask you, where can I find some proper tutorials for learning VHDL?

Comment: The most commonly recommended resource I see is a free eBook called Free Range VHDL from http://freerangefactory.org/books_tuts.html